# expression of type 'T' cannot be handled by a pattern of type '<null>'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

Here is a minimal sample:

```
class C {
  public bool F<T>(T x) => x is null;
}
```

The real code causing the issue is here https://github.com/kofifus/With/blob/master/With.cs#L35

Until today this compiled fine, but I just upgraded to

> Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Preview Version 16.1.0 Preview
>   2.0

The code now errors with:

```
Error CS8511 An expression of type 'T' cannot be handled by a pattern of type '<null>'. Please use language version 'preview' or greater to match an open type with a constant pattern.
```

What's going on here ? and what is the correct way to solve this ?

note1 - I don't want C# language preview ATM
note2 - It still compiles if I change `x is null` to `x==null`

Comment: `Until today this compiled fine` really? hrmmm, my spidy senses are tingling

Comment: It doesn't compile for me in an older environment - Are you sure your code does compile in an older environment? You tested just before posting?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I did. The real code is long so I went with an example. You can see it here - https://github.com/kofifus/With/blob/master/With.cs#L35 - that compiled through all VS19 previews 1.x but stopped working for preview 2.0

Comment: Can you use the negation of `is object` ?

Comment: @Eric, I don't understand what you mean ? also I am trying to understand _why_ the code above throw that error ?

Comment: I'm asking you what happens if you change it to `!(x is object)`, which should have the same semantics. Does that give a similar error, or does it work just fine?

Comment: If your question is "what changed when I upgraded", well, read the change logs and you'll know.

Comment: `if (!(src is object))` works fine

Comment: I am trying to understand why the code above throw that error ? and what is the best way to check for null here ?

Comment: It throws the error, because its not valid syntax, whether it was or not in a preview.. Well that's a different thing, that's what happens with previews

Comment: ok Thx - what does ` An expression of type 'T' cannot be handled by a pattern of type '<null>'` means ? is that related to the new nullable types feature ?

Comment: [Compiler Error CS0403] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0403

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding to the solution mentioned, the fact that this used to be working for you [is likely to be caused by a bug in the 2019 preview](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/compilers/CSharp/Compiler%20Breaking%20Changes%20-%20post%20VS2019.md).

> However, in Visual Studio 2019 we improperly permitted this to compile in language versions 7.0, 7.1, 7.2, and 7.3. In Visual Studio 2019 Update 1 we will make it an error (as it was in Visual Studio 2017), and suggest updating to preview or 8.0.

Seems like allowing `is null` in open generics *will* be part of C#8 and is [championed here](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1284). The error is likely to eventually [tell you to upgrade to C#8](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/34695#discussion_r272416661) (instead of 'preview') after it's released.

Comment: This is correct. `t is null` previously was disallowed by the language. We implemented the change to allow it in C# 8.0, but accidentally forgot to limit the change to that language version. This was fixed in Visual Studio 2019 update 1 and documented as a break (in case anyone had taken a dependency on that behavior).

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt your assertion this always worked.

**Update**

If it did work in a previous *preview*, it was probably due to a language feature that got dumped

Possibly you are trying to compare with `null` i.e `==`

```
public bool F<T>(T x) => x == null;
```

However, a more robust way of checking generics for equality is with `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`. This respects `IEquatable<T>` without boxing as well as `object.Equals`, and handles all the `Nullable<T>` and lifted nuances of *nullable* types

```
public bool F<T>(T x) => EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(x, default(T));
```

`Update`

Just for the record, ([as you can see here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQDABCCMDcCwAoEBmKAmCBhCBvJEhEBRqEARgPaUA2EAYgDwAqAfABTMQAeAlBAF5WEAITtuEAJYBnCJXIArAKYBjAC68EiIsW2k0IACwQAsu3749OwvXYA7JQHcpdtec0lCAXyRegA===))

```
public bool F<T>(T x) => !(x is object);
```

Basically just compiles to

```
public bool F<T>(T x)
{
    return x == null;
}
```

Which is the same as

```
public bool F<T>(T x) => x == null;
```

Comment: strange it did used to work .. the real line was here https://github.com/kofifus/With/blob/master/With.cs#L35

Comment: wow that's quite a mouthful, can you explain _why_ `is null` doesn't work here ?

Comment: @kofifus its just a more robust generic check, and works against the `default` value of the type, it also saves some `IL` due to boxing value types, however this does depend on your use case, and what level of null or default you want.

Comment: Thx! `what level of null or default you want` - what do you mean ? I just want ot check for null. Can you explain further or tell me where to find more info ? 
Also what is the difference between above and `if (!(x is object))` which works as well ?

Comment: The just use `== null` however what about default structs, and things like `new int()`

Comment: `is` checks against a type, and `null` is not a type, it's a value. Just like you can't do `x is 5`. You could do `x is string`, though.

Comment: got it thx! also seems there is no need for ` default(T)` - `default` is enough